# Why wont my PHPmailer script work to get / save files?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, phpmailer

I have an HTML / javascript form written with a loop to upload an unlimited amount of files with names="file1","file2",etc. (i++)

So now i have a PHP form to process it (get all files, save to temporary folder "uploads", and email as attachments using phpmailer).

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
//Variables Declaration
$name = "the Submitter";
$email_subject = "Images Attachment";
$Email_msg ="A visitor submitted the following :\n";
$Email_to = "you@yourSite.com"; // the one that recieves the email
$email_from = "someone@someone.net";
$dir = "uploads/$filename";
chmod("uploads",0777);
$attachments = array();

uploadFile();
//

//
//==============upload File Function============\\
//
function uploadFile() {
global $attachments;
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[images][name]))
{
//
if(!empty($value))
{
$filename = $value;
//the Array will be used later to attach the files and then remove them from server ! array_push($attachments, $filename);
$dir = "uploads/$filename";
chmod("uploads",0777);
$success = copy($_FILES[images][tmp_name][$key], $dir);
}
//
}
//
if ($success) {
echo " Files Uploaded Successfully<BR>";
SendIt();
//
}else {
exit("Sorry the server was unable to upload the files...");
}
//
}
//
//==== PHP Mailer With Attachment Func ====\\
//
function SendIt() {
//
global $attachments,$name,$Email_to,$Email_msg,$email_subject,$email_from;
//
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();// send via SMTP
$mail->Host = "localhost"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; // turn on/off SMTP authentication
$mail->From = $email_from;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress($Email_to);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email_from);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;// set word wrap
//now Attach all files submitted
foreach($attachments as $key => $value) { //loop the Attachments to be added ...
$mail->AddAttachment("uploads"."/".$value);
}
$mail->Body = $Email_msg."Name : ".$name."\n";
//
$mail->IsHTML(false);// send as HTML
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message was not sent <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
//
echo "Message has been sent";
// after mail is sent with attachments , delete the images on server ...
foreach($attachments as $key => $value) {//remove the uploaded files ..
unlink("uploads"."/".$value);
}
//
}
//
?>
```

But for some reason, im getting the following errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: filename in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 10

```
Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 11

Notice: Use of undefined constant images - assumed 'images' in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 22

Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 22

Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: success in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 36
Sorry the server was unable to upload the files...
```

If someone can help with ANY of these or give their input of a better way to do it, that would be so so helpful.

Thank you soooo much!!!

Comment: re your question title: I presume you mean "can I use..." rather than "can I sue..."????  ;-) (I've edited it for you, because that small typo makes it sound like your asking quite a different question!)

Comment: H.O.R.R.I.B.L.E code! (that makes for a movie title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First warning: You're chmodding the `uploads` directory itself. Unless the directory is owned by your webserver's user ID, you'll get the permission denied error - you cannot chmod something that does not belong to you.

Second and Third warning:  Your array keys in the `$_FILES` array are incorrect. They should be

```
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']['name']))
```

note the quotes - without the quotes, PHP assumes they're constants that were created via `define()`. If there's no constant by that name, PHP polite will treat them as strings of the same name, but issues the warning.

Fourth warning: You're misusing `each()`. Instead, just have:

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value) {
```

Fifth warning: The only place you assign a value to `$success` is within the `if()` that does the image copy, when the file copy succeeds. Since your code is broken, the copy never takes place, so `$success` is never defined. To fix, put a

```
$success = false;
```

somewhere at the top of your file, so it's defined with a default value.

Beyond that, don't use `copy()` on uploaded files. There's security issues involved with PHP and file uploads on shared servers. Use `move_uploaded_file()` instead. This will be a far cheaper operation as well, since moving a file within a single filesystem is near instantaneous, while `copy()` actually duplicates the file - on large files this gets expensive (time + cpu + disk space) very quickly.

---

comment followup:

It does matter how you name the input fields, as that'll determine how things show up in the files array.

If you go with the `file1`, `file2`, etc... option, you end up with:

```
$_FILES = array(
    'file1' => array('name' => ..., 'size' => ..., etc...),
    'file2' => array('name' => ..., 'size' => ..., etc...),
    etc...
)
```

If you do `files[]`, you end up with:

```
$_FILES = array (
   'files' => array
        'name' => array(
            0 = 'name of first file',
            1 = 'name of second file',
            ...
        'size' => array(
            0 = 'size of first file'
            1 = 'name of second file'
         etc...
```

A major structural difference. I have no idea why such a moronic difference was allowed to go into production, but since this is core PHP functionality, changing it to be more logically consistent is basically impossible.

Comment: Thanks You so much! You have no idea how big of a help this is.. Just one follow up.. 

I replaced 

    `while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[images][size])) `

With

    `foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value)` 

And now I am getting these errors: Thanks again for your help Marc

 

`Notice: Undefined index: images in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 21

    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/hom/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 21 `

Comment: Do you have an `<input type="file" name="images[]">` in your form? Is it also set to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: No i dont have `name="images[]`, I have a javascript form to, on click, add a new input field with the `name = file1`, then `file2` etc. Should i just change that to `images[]`? Will it cause a problem if theres multiple files with `name="images[]`? Thanks. Btw, it is multipart/form-data

Comment: Hmm. So youre saying theres no way to just grab all the files? I cant say grab all files beginning with name = file ending with whatever? -Marc B

Comment: depends on how you structure your form. After that it's just building the appropriate PHP loop to rummage around inside $_FILES.

Comment: What i do '$_FILES = array (
   'files' => array
        'name' => array(
            0 = 'name of first file',
            1 = 'name of second file',
            ...
        'size' => array(
            0 = 'size of first file'
            1 = 'name of second file'
         etc...'
And just go up to like file15 (no ones uploading more than that).. Will I run into trouble if theres less than 15 files uploaded?

Comment: there's an `error` parameter. If a file's uploaded properly, it's 0. If there's an error (including no file at all), it's non-zero. The codes are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Ive changed things up and im so close! This is the error i get now 'Notice: Undefined variable: filename in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 10' 

And the email gets sent, but the attachment doesnt which means its having trouble getting the file

Comment: You've got `$dir = "uploads/$filename";` on line 10, and $filename hasn't been defined yet... the error message is 100% accurate...

Comment: yeah but when I move that down to after $filename is defined, the error goes way but still no emails.. PS opened a new question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697161/why-is-phpmailer-not-sending-the-attachment Thanks again for your help