# Why is PHPmailer not sending the attachment?

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

Ive been working on create a file upload form using PHPmailer to send as attachments.

Ive finally got it to send the email, but its not sending the attachment. Here's my HTML form:

```
<input type="file" class="fileupload" name="images[]" size="80" />
```

And here's my php processor code:

```
<?php
require("css/class.phpmailer.php");
//Variables Declaration
$name = "the Submitter";
$email_subject = "Images Attachment";
$Email_msg ="A visitor submitted the following :\n";
$Email_to = "jonahkatz@yahoo.com"; // the one that recieves the email
$email_from = "someone@someone.net";
$attachments = array();
//
//
//------Check TYPE------\\
uploadFile();
//
//==============upload File Function============\\
//
function uploadFile() {
global $attachments;
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value)
{
//
if(!empty($value))
{
$filename = $value;
//the Array will be used later to attach the files and then remove them from ser
ver ! array_push($attachments, $filename);
$dir = "uploads/$filename";
$success = copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $dir);
}
//
}
$dir ="uploads/$filename";


if ($success) {
echo " Files Uploaded Successfully<BR>";
SendIt();
//
}else {
exit("Sorry the server was unable to upload the files...");
}
//
}
//
//==== PHP Mailer With Attachment Func ====\\
//
function SendIt() {
//
global $attachments,$name,$Email_to,$Email_msg,$email_subject,$email_from;
//
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsQmail();// send via SMTP
$mail->From = $email_from;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress($Email_to);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email_from);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;// set word wrap
//now Attach all files submitted
foreach($attachments as $key => $value) { //loop the Attachments to be added ...
$mail->AddAttachment("uploads"."/".$value);
}
$mail->Body = $Email_msg."Name : ".$name"\n";
//
$mail->IsHTML(false);// send as HTML
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message was not sent <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
//
echo "Message has been sent";
// after mail is sent with attachments , delete the images on server ...
foreach($attachments as $key => $value) {//remove the uploaded files ..
unlink("uploads"."/".$value);
}
//
}
//
?>
```

Ive checked, and the file IS being saved in the directory "uploads". Here are the errors im receiving:

```
Files Uploaded Successfully
Message was not sent


Notice: Undefined property: phpmailer::$ErrorInfo in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 69
Mailer Error:
```

If anyone can spot the errors or provide some input how to this that would be so helpful! Thanks in advanced!

Jonah

---

Ive replaced

```
foreach($attachments as $key => $value) { //loop the Attachments to be added ...
$mail->AddAttachment("uploads"."/".$value);
```

With

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['files']['name']) as $key) {
   $source = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]; // location of PHP's temporary file for this.
   $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]; // original filename from the client

   $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
}
```

And now here are my new errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: files in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 58

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 58

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 58

Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 68

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::IsHTML() in /usr/home/jak2234/public_html/new_form/phpmailerprocess.php on line 70
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695756/why-wont-my-phpmailer-script-work-to-get-save-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in your other question, the first warning is due to you using `$filename` in line 10 of your script, without having assigned a value to it first:

```
$dir ="uploads/$filename"; // $filename has NOT been defined at this point.
```

As well, for your attachments, why not simply do:

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['files']['name']) as $key) {
   $source = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]; // location of PHP's temporary file for this.
   $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]; // original filename from the client

   $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
}
```

There's no need to do all the file copying, building your own paths, etc... Just directly attach the temporary file PHP creates for you, and name it with whatever the original filename was.

Your script is far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Look Above - I added the new errors when using your better code. Thanks again.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES)`, which'll show you the exact structure of the array.

Comment: Ok. Here: 

`array(1) { ["images"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "logo.png" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/phpozhSdq" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(56306) } } } `

Comment: any input? Ive been working on this for so long, just cant get it done.

Comment: The first notice says it all. "undefined index files". On line 58, there's no `files` index in the array. Your dump above says it's now "images". Don't be scared of error messages... they do help.